# AngularJS ng-Grid starts minimized?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm using ng-Grid v2.0.7, and the problem is that the first time that ng-grid shows, it is minimized. Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Only after clicking on the minimized table (the top picture), the full table displays normally (the bottom picture)..
Here is the code I'm using:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'jsonData.value',
    multiSelect: false
};
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT: Here is the definition in the html file:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-show="(dataViewType == 'table')" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

Comment: What css does your grid div have (usually class gridStyle)?

Comment: There is no css applied on the class gridStyle.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `ng-cloak` directive on your grid element.

For example on a simple div :

```
<div ng-cloak></div>
```

> "The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display."

Docs : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just tried what you suggested and it still starts minimized :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was caused by CSS properties.

It was because I set height & width as percentages, rather than a fixed number of pixels.

Changing them to a fixed number of pixels removed the problem (leaving me only with the problem of what values to choose to accommodate my dynamic JSON data).

I ended up with this in my controller:

```
    $scope.getTableStyle= function() {
       var rowHeight=30;
       var headerHeight=45;
       return {
          height: (gridHeaderHeight + 1 + 
                  ($scope.myGrid.length * (gridRowHieght + 1))) + "px"
       };
    };
```

and this in my HTML

```
   <div ng-show="myGrid" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" 
        ng-style="getTableStyle()" ng-cloak></div>
```

In order to calculate the grid size whenever I periodically fetch new JSON data from the server.